# How to nullify setColorFilter method?

Tags: android

Hey I have this Image that I make it black when the activity starts using this code
 `img.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));`
but I want to change it to normal when the user clicks on a button. so any idea on how to nullify this method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the `colorFilter` by *nulling it*

```
setColorFilter(null);
```

> Specify an optional color filter for the drawable. Pass null to remove any existing color filter.
>
> Parameters
>   cf  the color filter to apply, or null to remove the existing color filter